# How to export only the selected mesh as .fbx to Unreal engine?

Tags: export, .fbx

I have the following scene from which I want to export a single character as a .fbx file:

[image]

But upon export with the following settings:

[image]

And trying to import it into unreal engine 4, I get the following:

[image]

How to fix this? In general, how to correctly export only the selected mesh?

Also, importing the .fbx to blender itself shows no mesh.

Comment: To check whether it is the problem of the .fbx file I would recommend you to open another new blender workspace and import the .fbx back to blender itself.

Comment: Can you share the .fbx file? With the same model I could export and import back to blender itself.

Comment: Would you share two separate fbx files for male and female meshes?